# How to enable Httpclient for springboot 2.0.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, httpclient, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am using for my project the version 2.0.2 release of springboot.
I need to use HttpClient class for my project.
could you help me please how to enable httpClient for this release?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hint that could help you.

Start by registering an HttpClient bean in a Spring Config class like this:

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;


@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public HttpClient httpClient() {
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(30 * 1000).build();
    return HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
  }

}
```

Then you can access by two ways:

"Autowirering" the field in the component

```
@Autowired
private HttpClient httpClient;
```

Or injecting it in the component's constructor like this:

```
@Service
public class MyClass{
  private final HttpClient httpClient;

  @Autowired
  public MyClass(HttpClient httpClient){
    this.httpClient = httpClient;
  }
}
```

I personally prefer the second approach which makes it more understandable and easier at the moment of testing, you just provide a mock to the instance of the class you want to test.